# open database for login account in ios

Tags: ios, sqlite, compiler-errors

I am very new to `iOS`.
   I am trying to create login page using the utility application in `IOS 7`. I created one *view controller* with `sqlite` database  and I need to open that database in another *view controller*. If I try means, I got a break point error or signal error

### Here is my code:

```
(void)login {
const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                          @"SELECT username FROM contacts WHERE username=\"%@\"",
                          username.text ];


    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];


    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB,
                           query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)

    {
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
                   loginstatus.text=@"login sucessful";

        }
        else {
            loginstatus.text = @"Match not found";
        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
else
{
    loginstatus.text=@"no db";
}

sqlite3_close(contactDB);
}
@end
```

Comment: i need to create login page like gmail login page

Comment: sorry for confusing you. if u creating facebook or gmail account newly means  they have some steps to create .that only i am trying i am created db and stored datas in one table.but i am try to open that database in another view controller is getting error.

Comment: now the datas are stord in db if it is sure, then u want to move the value from one view controller to a noter view controller u need the singleton class or app delegate[shared application]; method, r u got my point

Comment: sorry for disturbs i got breakpoint error while i am using app delegate[share property]

Comment: what the error u get on console

Comment: @Pavan:i done that pa. using singleton class.thanks for you.